# How to create a KDE start application menu launcher that launches the search and launch desktop?

Tags: kde, kubuntu, plasma

Now i love the [plasma-netbook](http://www.kde.org/workspaces/plasmanetbook/) aka the "search and launch" interface but i would want to be able to have it appear on demand and not sit as the desktop default in the back of my windows.

So what i imagine is having a application launcher be created which on activation brings up the "search and launch" feature allowing for easy access of your favorites or have that slick interface to find what your looking for. I'm aware that krunner solves a similar use-case but search and launch would be more of an Unity Dash type of search, whereas krunner is more useful when u exactly know what your looking for.

And to summarize my question, since I'm clueless as to how this would be done, I'm lookinf for someone who could tell me how hard it would be to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think i may have found the best possible alternative to my search. Its this new plasmoid called ["Takeoff"](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/07/takeoff-launcher-adds-mac-launchpadslingshot-launcher-kde/). It's not really the netbook interface but i must say I'm pretty pleased with its 1st release.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a new activity and set its desktop layout as "search and launch".
You can quickly switch between activities using a keyboard shortcut(default Meta+Tab) or using the "Activity Bar" widget.

If you want to read more about Plasma Activities, visit http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=93183 .

Comment: i was thinking about this, as well as just using separate widgets for my workspaces. this would give me one which can act as a launcher. but i would really like to know how hard it would be to make a start menu associated with the search and launch feature. that would be ideal. if not then i guess ill settle for what can be done without coding.